# Spark-Java API : SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate() Fails?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to run a sample standalone Spark-Java Program.  Seems though some dependent library is missing...

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[1]");
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());  
SQLContext sc = new SQLContext(spark);
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LogicalRDD overrides final method sameResult.(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/QueryPlan;)Z
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sparkwrapper.SparkTest.main(SparkTest.java:19)
17/11/20 12:19:48 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be eclipse (Neon 3) configuration issues.